# Mercurial - a simple way to lock a repository

Tags: mercurial

My scenario:
A set of shared repositories needs to be locked for a given time so a process can run for a given time. After this process is done, I want to unlock the repositories.  It's a process not on the repositories, but on a different system.

The repositories are not what the process is working on. I just need a time frame where the repositories are "protected". I just need to make sure the repositories don't change while this process is running.

I want a simple way to lock a repository, so no one can push to it.
If I manually create a **.hg/store/lock** file with a dummy content, do you see any problem with it?

Initial testing shows it works, but I'm concerned that I might not be aware of the implications.

Comment: You should instead set up a good web publishing of the repository, complete with authentication, and then just hand out read-only users

Comment: I already have a web setup. I just want to lock a repository for a given time for all users and unlock it after an event is done.  I'll explain the scenario in the question in more details...

Comment: By adding that lock, you're effectively preventing Mercurial from doing *anything* to that repository. What kind of process are you running on the repository?

Comment: It's a process not on the repositories, but on a different system. I just need to make sure the repositories don't change while this process is running.

Comment: I don't see why changing the repositories would have anything to say here. I'm hoping you're not synchronizing Mercurial repositories using anything but mercurial?

Comment: No. I'm not. This is a "just in case" lock. Everything else is strictly HG!

Comment: What about running your process on clones of the repositories. That is the clones are created solely for the "process" and not pushed too by any other component.

Comment: The repositories are not what the process is working on. I just need a time frame where the repositories are "protected"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to generally deny access to the repos for a given period, then you can do it that way. There shouldn't be any side-effects or other consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repository and then run your process against the cloned repo.